# What type of web service and how to connect from iOS

Tags: c#, iphone, objective-c

I need to connect to a webservice from my iOS app however I can't figure out how to connect to it and what classes I need to use etc.

I can't give the real URL but this is what I can say - when I open the following in the browser it asks for a username and password. I think it might be PHP or Java?

http://IPADDRESS/XmlServlet/Dispatcher?action

I do have the code that one requires but its in C#.  I need it in objective c:

```
public void SendXML(string xml)
        {
            xtvRequest.Xml = xml;
            string actionName = xml.LastIndexOf(":")<xml.LastIndexOf("</") ?
                xml.Substring(xml.LastIndexOf("</")+2,xml.Length-3-xml.LastIndexOf("</")) :
                xml.Substring(xml.LastIndexOf(":")+1,xml.Length-2-xml.LastIndexOf(":"));
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=UTF-8");
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
            Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
            s.Start();
            byte[] bret = client.UploadData("http://IPADDRESS/TTXmlServlet/Dispatcher?action=" + actionName, "POST",
            System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml));
            s.Stop();
            string sret = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bret);
            xtvResponse.Xml = sret;
            tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1;
        }
```

And this is how the request looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><n1:SearchEngineRequest xmlns:n1="http://domain.com/searchengine/request" LanguageCode="EN_GB" Timestamp="2010-10-11T16:53:07Z" Target="Test" SessionID=""></n1:SearchEngineRequest>
```

Comment: Make sure you look into using REST services with JSON!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either use NSURLConnection and implement basic authentication in order to access the web service but I suggest that you use the [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) library for this, it makes your life much easier. Check out this part: [Handling HTTP Authentication](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#handling_http_authentication)

Comment: Agreed. This is the way to go.